# R - How to avoid ending up with unwanted characters like Â when using ± symbol in exported tables from R for later use in Excel?

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I want to make tables with ± using R (e.g.  10 ± 1 ) and export the file as a csv file. The trouble is that when I open the csv file with Excel, 10 ± 1 becomes 10 Â± 1.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem within R? I expect many people who access my csv file would do so by using Excel. Copy-and-paste becomes rather cumbersome with many files with those ± characters. Thanks!

example:

```
dat <- matrix(ncol=2, nrow=1)
dat[1,1] <- "10 ± 1"
dat[1,2] <- "10"
rownames(dat) <- "trial 1"
colnames(dat) <- c("estimate ± sem", "t estimate")
write.csv(dat, "table.csv")
```

also tried without success:

```
dat[1,1] <- "10 \u00b1 1"
Encoding(dat) <- "UTF-8"
write.csv(dat, "table.csv")
```

This worked!

```
write.csv(dat, "table.csv", fileEncoding="Windows-1252")
```

... solution derived from
http://theoldsewingfactory.com/2010/12/05/saving-csv-files-in-utf8-creates-a-characters-in-excel/

Highlight from the link above: It turns out that for all Excel’s sophistication it doesn’t like UTF-8 encoded files. It’s much more at home with files encoded as Windows-1252, well at least for Latin languages.

Comment: How do you export ? I guess `write.table`( or some wrapper)? try to set `fileEncoding` to `UTF-8`.